# c++ inheritance: can a pointer to a base class access members of the derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Given a base class `Shape` and a derived class `Rectangle`, I want to access the member variable `size` of Rectangle by the following code:

```
class Shape
{
    public:
      Shape() {};
};

class Rectangle
{
public:
   Rectangle(int width) {width=width;}
   int width;
};


//execute this code during runtime
std::shared_ptr<Shape> ptr = std::make_shared<Rectangle>();
ptr->width; // is this possible ???
```

I am having a more complicated code, where this results in an error. Conversely, if `compute_area()` were an overwritten member function of `Rectangle`, `ptr->compute_area()` would give no error.

Comment: If `Shape` doesn't have a `width` member, then it won't work. You need to *downcast* the pointer. Or come up with an interface that can be generic enough to be abstracted in the `Shape` class and called like any other virtual and polymorphic function.

Comment: No, Shape has no member called width. In fact, Shape and Rectangle share only member functions but no member variables.

Comment: question title says "*access members of the base class*" however you are actually trying to accesses members of the derived class. This obviously won't work.

Comment: I added a minimal working example. So the concept of polymorphism works only for member functions that are defined in both abstract and base class?

Comment: Concept of polymorphism works only for `virtual` member functions.

Comment: As your code is currently written, `Rectangle` is completely unrelated to `Shape`.

Comment: *"Both abstract and base class"*. Typically the base class is the abstract class. ITYM base class and derived class.

Comment: The purpose of my MWE was just to illustrate my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code contains a big problem. Rectangle does not inherit from Shape, so `std::shared_ptr<Shape> ptr = std::make_shared<Rectangle>();` will throw an error. You need to `class Rectangle : public Shape` to fix it

As for access to the member variable width via ptr, you will need to cast Shape to Rectangle. You can do it a few ways, which will depend on what you're code is doing. If you are 100% sure ptr can cast to Rectangle, you can do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Shape> ptr = std::make_shared<Rectangle>();
auto rect = std::static_pointer_cast<Rectangle>(ptr);
rect->width; // you can now access it
```

However, you should always evaluate your need to do this in the first place. Casting like this is usually a really big code smell that indicates a flaw in your design or approach to the problem. There are times when it is appropriate to make cast like this, but without seeing the rest of your code there is no way to make that assessment here. I suggest you avoid casting, look into why you need to do it with your current design, and redesign around not needing the cast. This sounds easier than it is, especially if you are new to it, but it is well worth doing for writing maintainable code.

Comment: Casting is totally useless and kills whole purpose of common Shape interface.  The point is to create Shape that can be Circle, Rectangle , Cube.  If you are 100% sure ptr can be casted to Rectangle  you coupled with Rectangle . And if you already coupled this will do std::shared_ptr<Rectangle> ptr = std::make_shared<Rectangle>() .

Comment: @fggrh you're making a lot of assumptions without any context here, so i have to disagree. there are cases where casting like this absolutely makes sense, but without the context there is no way to make the conclusion you've made. my answer provides a way to accomplish what was asked, but my last paragraph addresses that this could be a poor way to handle this and explains why. normally i would agree with you, but without context it cannot be assumed a default bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

To make what you want you need common interface for Shape and Derived to solve `compute_area()`:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual int metnodA() = 0;
    virtual int compute_area() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {};
};

class Rectangle:public Shape
{
    int width;
public:
    Rectangle(int w):width(w) {}
    int metnodA()override {
        return width;
    };
    int compute_area() override {
        //your implementation
    };
}
```

While direct access to width is impossible since `Shape` has no such member.